# Disable the Check Boxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to disable the checkboxes on clicking like in my code. If the user clicks on checkbox A then checkbox B and C should be disabled but if the user click checkbox B or C only A will be disabled. Users will be able to multi-select B and C . A Should be single-select in every case.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike" class="a"> A
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Car" class="b"> B
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike" class="c"> C
```

Comment: You forgot to include the JavaScript you tried that didn't work. Also, it's `type="checkbox"`, not `type="check box"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After fixing your html:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike" class="a"> A
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Car" class="b"> B
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike" class="c"> C
```

You could do something like this:

```
$("input").click(function(){
        var _class=$(this).attr('class');
        if($(this).is(':checked')){
            if(_class=='a'){
                    $('.b').attr('disabled','disabled');
                    $('.c').attr('disabled','disabled');
            }else if(_class=='b' || _class=='c'){
                $('.a').attr('disabled','disabled');
            }
        }else{
            if($("input:checked").length==0){
                $("input").removeAttr('disabled');
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: You should try using `.prop()` instead of `.attr()` - the former works better with boolean attributes.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, did not read the question fully and missed that only A should be disabled if B or C was checked. Here's a working version, including my added spans (used to change the label color for disabled inputs):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('input').change(function(){
        if ($(this).is(':checked') && $(this).hasClass('a')) {
            $('input').not('.a').attr('disabled', true);
            $('input').not('.a').next('span').css('color', '#888888');
        } else if ($('.b').is(':checked') || $('.c').is(':checked')) {
            $('.a').attr('disabled', true);
            $('.a').next('span').css('color', '#888888');
            $('input').not('.a').attr('disabled', false);
        } else {
            $('input').attr('disabled', false);
            ('span').css('color', '');
        }
    });
});
```

A fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nfcTE/2/